# Is there any way to set transaction isolation level in EJB in its deployment descriptor itself?

Tags: ejb-3.0

Is there any way to set the transaction isolation level in EJB in its deployment descriptor itself? Do we have that flexibility?

I meant transaction isolation level. For bean managed transactions we can set the isolation in a resource manager API like JDBC. I was thinking if in any way we can set the container managed transactions isolation level in a deployment descriptor?

Comment: What do you mean by 'isolation level'?

Comment: Do you mean the JDBC isolation level? If so, then I think you're making a common mistake of confusing the terms "EJB" and "JPA".

Comment: Thank you.. i meant transaction isolation level. for bean managed transactions we can set isolation in resource manager API like JDBC right...I was thinking if any way we can set container managed transactions isolation level in DD??

Answer (score 1):

The transaction isolation level is a property of the resource that participates in a transaction. It's unrelated to whether the user manages the transaction (Bean Managed Transactions, BMT) or that the container does that (Container Managed Transactions, CMT).

The only thing EJB does is start, propagate and commit or rollback transactions via JTA. What exactly constitutes as a transaction for each resource is up to that resource.

See this answer for a more detailed explanation: [How do i set the Transaction Isolation in EJB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642881/how-do-i-set-the-transaction-isolation-in-ejb)