# Adding Isolation level in EJB

Tags: hibernate, transactions, jboss, ejb, isolation-level

I need to define Isolation level at Transaction level in EJB3.

I am using EJB3 and Jboss as Application server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i set the Transaction Isolation in EJB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642881/how-do-i-set-the-transaction-isolation-in-ejb)

Answer (score 0):

Umm... `@Transactional(value =...)` ? Is this what you're after?

Comment: This is not EjB. But it should be possible to control the transactions using that on normal CDI-Beans.

Comment: @Transactional annotation is not available in EJB.

Answer (score 0):

EJB doesn't define any specific API for managing isolation levels. I recommend you look at this post: [How do i set the Transaction Isolation in EJB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642881/how-do-i-set-the-transaction-isolation-in-ejb) (Arthur Ronald answer).